# Determine the Index of UserForms in the Collection

Tags: vba, userform

I am working on a VBA "application" that I did not initially write.  The application uses a couple of different UserForms. The original coder referenced the individual userforms by referencing their position in the UserForms() collection.  Ex `UserForms(MainFormID)` where `Integer MainFormID` is `0`

However, I recently made a change that added another UserForm. However, (I'm thinking) this changed the index values of some of the other forms, so lines like `UserForms(MainFormID).SomeControl.SomeMethod` are throwing errors. Even weirder, this only seems to happen after I run the app once; It runs perfectly fine the first time.

Instead of hard coding `MainFormID = 0` and `LinkFormID = 1`, I'd like to the program to determine the index of the forms based on their keys (names).

Is there something like `LinkFormID = UserForms("LinkForm").index`?

Comment: The index is determined by the order of items in the container, by the container - not by the items.

Comment: I know, but is there a way to find out which order the container has placed the items?

Comment: Iterate the container and find out?